# Creation of a FA2 Token (Fungible) and not an NFT

Tags: smart-contracts, nft, fa2, blockchain

I created a smart contract to do several interactions with tokens.
With the tutorial on the tezos website: https://tezos.com/developers/tutorials/nft-markeplace

Here is my smart contract: https://legacy.smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmZWtv3TBjX97XEQcu1mqGfDZe73hiyZw4Y4tMVxYv9qVB&k=6ec679c3854a4df89088

The smart contract works very well, but the problem is that when I look on the blockchain, my token is a FA2 (a fungible token) and not an NFT...

Here is a token that I generate with the mint of my smart contract:

[image: FA2 Token]

As you can see in the photo below the token is identified as "OTHER" and not as "NFT"

[image: OTHER NOT NFT]

Operation link: https://ghostnet.tzkt.io/opJECYmKonLh32hLwhn4EHBmNCn6i2C36X2ZxCaXxbzm8SJjd2R/17051811

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two Token Standards on Tezos. [FA1.2](https://tzip.tezosagora.org/proposal/tzip-12/) and [FA2](https://tzip.tezosagora.org/proposal/tzip-7/). There is no separate standard for NFTs. So this is indeed correct, FA2 standard is an Multi-Asset Interface, also the NFT abbreviation stands for Non fungible token.

Just a sidenote, there is currently a discussion about a "new" standard [FA2.1](https://forum.tezosagora.org/t/fa2-1-as-extension-of-the-fa2-standard-draft/4768) which would act as extension to FA2.

You can check on [TZComet](https://tzcomet.io/#/explorer) if your contract metadata is correct.

Comment: Owww, Okey thanks, and why on the image, it is written: "OTHER" ?

Answer (score 2):

FA2.0 standard doesn't describe how to distinguish NFT from non-NFT, so there is actually no way to precisely tell what your token is.

TzKT uses heuristics to classify tokens. In particular, it classifies a token as NFT if it contains `artifactUri` in its metadata (like [this one](https://tzkt.io/KT1EHHGSrV8xi8psZsfG42VvPozc9YPmrZ2Y/tokens/34/metadata)), according to recommendations from [TZIP-21](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tzip/-/blob/master/proposals/tzip-21/tzip-21.md). But your token doesn't have it. Moreover, the metadata of your token is not indexed at all, because you have specified an incorrect uri `ipfs://bafyreigr3iryqlttwkx3xuoml7orhskd5mj2ffcioqyynz44mft7v5q4ca/metadata.json||marcheeee`.

Therefore, without metadata TzKT can say nothing about your token, so that's why it is classified as "other".